# What is wrong with the following code?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, ora-00904

```
select trigger_name from user_triggers where owner = 'WC';
```

WC is the schema name.

The error I get is :

> ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier
>
> 1. 00000 -"%s: invalid identifier"
>
> *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 14 Column: 45

Comment: Learn `DESC`. It's very useful for diagnosing ORA-904.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no owner in user_triggers table. There is table_owner.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

ORA-00904:  string: invalid identifier

Cause:  The column name entered is either missing or invalid.

Action: Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with a letter, be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #. If it contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. It may not be a reserved word.

[Oracle Error Description](http://ora-00904.ora-code.com/)

Sometimes it happends if you don't have enough access rights on your DB.